# swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I am receiving a "swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined" error when creating a CursorLoader. I have 
imported the android.support.v4 (app.LoaderManager, app.LoaderManager.Loader, Content.CursorLoader, content.Loader). Not sure what I can do to correct this issue. please advise.

loader:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
 import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
 import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
 import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
 import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;


 public class LoginList extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);

loginList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

webLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);



//Specify fileds to display in the list
String[] from = new String[] { ListProvider.COLUMN_NAME_SITE };

//Bind fields to listview
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.loginlist};

// Create CursorAdapter and set it to display
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.login_listview, null, from, to);

loginList.setAdapter(adapter);

getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


/*@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
setEmptyText(getResources().getString(string.app_name));
rwgisterForContextMenu(getListView());
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    } */


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);


    Cursor clickedObject = (Cursor)loginList.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getsName());
loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getwUrl());
loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getuName());
loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getpWord());
loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getlNotes());

updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
startActivity(webLoginIntent);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int ignored, final Bundle args) {
return new CursorLoader(this, ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
 }

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
adapter.swapCursor(cursor); /* swapCursor error: The method swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type SimpleCursorAdapter */


 }

 @Override
 public void onLoaderReset (Loader<Cursor> loader) {
adapter.swapCursor(null); /* swapCursor error: The method swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type SimpleCursorAdapter */

  }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the latest Android Support package JAR? Unfortunately, the JavaDocs for these support classes do not mention when methods were added, and so it is possible that `swapCursor()` was a more recent addition.

Comment: I have verified through my SDK Manager, I have REV 12 of the Support Library installed. This is the latest library available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was resolved by importing v4.widget.simplecursoradapter.

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```